# Riverpood does not update the status until I enter the screen

Tags: flutter, state-management, riverpod

I have a general configuration screen, with a button that syncs the data

```
(...)
appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          Row(
            children: [
              const Text(ConfigurationsStringsUI.updateGeneral),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.sync),
                onPressed: () {
                  ref.read(listProductController.notifier).syncProducts();
                  ref.read(listEmployedController.notifier).syncEmployees();
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
(...)
```

In the case of products, it has a specific screen that is responsible for managing them, basically a CRUD. When I press the sync button, the idea is to connect to supabase and update the data. While this is happening display a loadign. The problem is that the loading does not appear.
`products_page.dart`

```
GetIt sl = GetIt.instance;

class CRUDProduct extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                ref.read(listProductController.notifier).syncProducts();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.update),
            )
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: ref.watch(isVisibleFabProducts)
            ? FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: scaffoldKey.currentContext!,
                    builder: (context) => AddProductDialog(),
                  );
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.fastfood),
              )
            : null,
        body: ref.watch(listProductController).when(
          data: (products) {
            if (products.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text(ProductStringsUI.emptyList),
              );
            } else {
              return NotificationListener<UserScrollNotification>(
                onNotification: (notification) {
                  if (notification.direction == ScrollDirection.forward) {
                    ref.read(isVisibleFabProducts.notifier).state = true;
                  }
                  if (notification.direction == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
                    ref.read(isVisibleFabProducts.notifier).state = false;
                  }
                  return true;
                },
                child: ListView.separated(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ItemProductList(product: products[index]);
                    },
                    separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                    itemCount: products.length),
              );
            }
          },
          error: (error, stackTrace) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text(ProductStringsUI.errorList),
            );
          },
          loading: () {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Product provider:

```
final listProductController =
    StateNotifierProvider<ProductController, AsyncValue<List<LocalProduct>>>(
        (ref) => ProductController(ref));
```

product_controller.dart

```
class ProductController extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<List<LocalProduct>>> {
  ProductController(this._ref) : super(const AsyncValue.loading()) {
    getProducts();
  }
  final Ref _ref;

  Future<void> getProducts() async {
    try {
      final employees = await sl.get<ListProductUseCase>().getProducts();

      if (mounted) {
        state = AsyncValue.data(employees);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(e, StackTrace.current);
    }
  }

  Future<void> syncProducts() async {
    try {
      _ref.read(listCategoryController.notifier).state =
          const AsyncValue.loading();
      _ref.read(listEmployedController.notifier).state =
          const AsyncValue.loading();
      state = const AsyncValue.loading();
      await _ref.read(listCategoryController.notifier).syncCategory();
      final employees = await sl.get<SyncProductUseCase>().syncProducts();
      state.whenData((value) {
        if (mounted) {
          state = AsyncValue.data([...value, ...employees]);
        }
      });
      _ref.invalidate(listProductController);
    } catch (e) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(e, StackTrace.current);
    }
  }
  }
```

In the case of products, it has a specific screen that is responsible for managing them, basically a CRUD. When I press the sync button, the idea is to connect to supabase and update the data. While this is happening display a loadign. The problem is that the loading does not appear. There are two scenarios:

1-I open the app, I press the sync button on the configuration screen, I enter the screen in charge of managing the products, I see the loaded products, and at the moment it updates me with the new data, when I should see the loading and then the new ones data.
In this scenario is where my biggest doubt about the strange behavior is.

2-I open the app, I enter the screen in charge of managing the products, I go to the configuration screen, I press sync, and in that case if I go to enter if the loading appears

The same goes for employees.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an async provider in Riverpod, you should tell it to load:

```
Future<void> addTopic(String name) async {
state = const AsyncValue.loading(); // Here

state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async { // And then you guard the value

  // Inside the brackets do all the logic of the function
  final currentId = ref.watch(currentSubjectProvider);
  final topicRepo = ref.watch(topicRepoProvider);

  await topicRepo.addTopic(currentId!, name);
  return _getTopics();
});
}
```

This example of mine, is a real project I am working on, and this is loading as expected, but I should mention that I am using the Riverpod generator, so if the generator did something, I am unaware of it. 
If you set the state to loading and guard the value, all listerners of that provider should be loading correctly.

Comment: ```_ref.read(listCategoryController.notifier).state =
          const AsyncValue.loading();``` i have this line of code...any other idea?

Comment: Never change state outside the notifier.  In fact, you should be using AsyncNotifier[Provider], not the legacy StateNotifier[Provider] or *shudder* StateProvider.